# PHP: Class constants in type declarations of input paramaters

Tags: php, parameters, typing, class-constants

For a custom logger I want to force the caller to pass a valid class constant defined in `Psr\Log\LogLevel`.

This class is defined like:

```
namespace Psr\Log;
/**
 * Describes log levels.
 */
class LogLevel
{
    const EMERGENCY = 'emergency';
    const ALERT     = 'alert';
    const CRITICAL  = 'critical';
    const ERROR     = 'error';
    const WARNING   = 'warning';
    const NOTICE    = 'notice';
    const INFO      = 'info';
    const DEBUG     = 'debug';
}
```

The loggers' function (*wrong*) looks like:

```
public static function log($log, LogLevel $logLevel = null): void {
   // .....
}
```

This does not work because LogLevel::DEBUG for instance is a string and not an instance of the class. Is there any way to enforce a class constant in a PHP type declaration? Because if I define `string` then you can pass any string obviously, but I just want to allow the declared constants.

Comment: Try with LogLevel::$logLevel

Comment: @Nullable How shall I declare that without a syntax error?

Comment: I don't think this is possible ; You should ether instantiate a LogLevel with a defined LogLevel, or have a check method into your log method.

Comment: I agree with @Bobot

Comment: @Bobot Yes I can check for the correct value within the function but then the answer is that PHP does not provide any possibility to declare this in a type declaration?

Comment: @Blackbam well this is not described in PHP docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't have constant restrictions, only types.

But you can do a workaround like this:

```
class LogLevel
{
    protected string $logName;

    private function __construct(string $logName)
    {
        $this->logName = $logName;
    }
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->logName;
    }

    public static function emergency(): self
    {
        return new self('emergency');
    }

    public static function alert(): self
    {
        return new self('alert');
    }

    public static function critical(): self
    {
        return new self('critical');
    }
    // create the other constants here
}
```

Now your static funcion works

```
public static function log($log, LogLevel $logLevel = null): void {
   // .....
}
```

`$logLevel` will receive `LogLevel::emergency()`, `LogLevel::critical()`, etc. and you can get the level name just calling `$logLevel->getName()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have Phpstorm you could use new `#[ExpectedValues]` attribute feature: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/10/phpstorm-2020-3-eap-4/#expectedvalues_examples

Comment: Exciting feature thanks for sharing ! Just be careful : this won't be applied on runtime this is just PHPStorm feature.

Comment: This does not validate if the caller passed the correct value though, those are just suggestions which constants are available?

Comment: Yes, you should consider it like `Static Analysis Tool`. But if you want to check it on runtime, you should make it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way but you could check if the inserted string matches certain values

```php
function checkLog(string $logLevel){
  $acceptableValues = array("emergency", "error", "debug");
  if(!in_array($logLevel, $acceptableValues) die();
}
```

Replace the strings in the array with the consts of your class.